# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite using Ubuntu and InteliJ

Tags: java, sqlite, java-11

There so many aked this, nearly simular, here i Stackoverlow. i read twenty of them. But i need ask anyway.

I created a db successful so:

```
cd ~/ ..... /resources
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
sqlite3 mydatabase.db
```

[image]

In Java (inteliJ) i get Error:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:resources:mydatabase.db

```
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:resources:mydatabase.db";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
```

mydatabase.db

Comment: Is a suitable jdbc driver in your classpath?

Comment: @rkosegi i could access sqlite3 from everywhere. example:  `cd ~ $ sqlite3`

Comment: @SL5net that doesn't mean you have the correct jar in your classpath. Just that you installed the sqlite client.

Comment: @rkosegi thanks i added dependencies to pom.xml get errors. its red: https://i.imgur.com/Sr0ITRw.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following entry to `dependencies` of pom.xml of your project

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.34.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc) for more specific version

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:resources:mydatabase.db

Comment: did you do clean build?

Comment: i using the menus from inteliJ for build. Build, run or debug. yes i rebuld there

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have downloaded the sqlite-jdbc jar file and added it as a library for this module.  [Here](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) is a link to the driver on GitHub with step-by-step instructions to implement it into your module.

Comment: thanks its solved already: here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66493660/2891692 .

Answer (score -1):

Very thanks to [silentsudo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1752366/silentsudo) answer. I tried edit his answer, add a little, and ask him, but he was not available anymore for me like so.

Now his very good answer with little needet modification:

```
Please add the following entry to `dependencies` of pom.xml of your project
```

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.34.0</version>
</dependency>
```

probalby the its red in inetliJ.

press then: File > invalid cache > and restart intellij

then pom should not look red. and and it should work

Check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc) for more specific version

```
in inteliJ you need also to in last step invalid cache and restart intellij
```